# Why is there a parsing error for the variable I feel that I have defined?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am writing what I feel is correct in parsing a variable with a function within, but the initial variable seems not to be defined.

```
let GameManager = {

  setGameStart: function(classType) {
    this.dealPlayers(classType);
  },

  dealPlayers: function{alert(7);}
}
```

> gvFDok9:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: GameManager is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gvFDok9:10) onclick @ gvFDok9:10 w4sgi3h:127 GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:63620/content/9GY1tH-AZhQ3KYlkAAAO/wvJ1XYA/aG5pE9Y/UBMpN7U/0wvYxWw/img/arena-bg.png
>   404 (Not Found) VM94 pokerTryOne.js:11 Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the line `dealPlayers: function{alert(7);}}`.

I believe you need a set of parenthesis before the first curly brace. Try:
`dealPlayers: function(){ alert(7); }`

The variable is not defined because that line causes a syntax error.

Comment: No problem. Please upvote/accept this answer if it was useful :)